# How to pass multiple value as same name using HttpServletRequest(Spring Freamework)?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have two input field in view

```
<input name="test[]" type="text" value="one">
<input name="test[]" type="text" value="two">
```

in controller

```
public String store(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
 // now i get only last value
 String[] array = request.getPerameter("test");

}
```

in PHP i can value as array using same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use request.getParameterValues(test)

Please check [**oracle doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)) for more info and here is an **[example](http://www.java4s.com/java-servlet-tutorials/example-on-getparametervalues-method-of-servlet-request/)**

Comment: get error like .......Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/store", method=RequestMethod.POST, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)  
 @ResponseBody 
 public WSResponse store(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {String[] aa = request.getParameterValues("test");
  System.out.println(aa[0]); return null;}

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="myForm"  th:action="@{/demo}"  method="post"
    class="stdform" id="triggerform">


    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="usr">test:</label>
            <input  name="test" type="text" class="form-control"   />
             <input name="test" type="text" class="form-control"   />
             <input name="test" type="text" class="form-control"  />
             <input name="test" type="text" class="form-control"  />
             <input name="test" type="text" class="form-control"   />
             <input name="test" type="text" class="form-control"   />


     </div>



            <button type="submit"   class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</button>

</form>

    @RequestMapping(value = "/demo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void getInboxMessage(HttpServletRequest request,Model model, @RequestParam("test") List<String> test) {

    try {
        logger.info("Welcome to getInboxMessage Method inside the MessageController ");
        System.out.println(test);
        }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
    }
    }
```

This would be spring way of doing it .hope it helps